# Authentication using python requests with passport js server

Tags: node.js, python-requests, passport.js

I was trying to make CLI tool for accessing my API. This API is created with Express.Js and does authentication using Passport.js and tool will be made in Python. I want to ask how can I authenticate a request sent from python's request library with the csrf tokens and everything. I have tried simple authentication and looked through many stackoverflow answers but nothing is really helping in this specific situation. Here's what the login form looks like.

```
<form action="/login/password" method="post">
<section>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" autocomplete="username" required autofocus>
</section>
<section>
    <label for="current-password">Password</label>
    <input id="current-password" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="current-password" required>
</section>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
<button type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

And this is how the `/login/password` route mentioned in the code above is handled.

```
router.post('/login/password', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureMessage: true
}));
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out when I tried to problem solve instead of scavenging on google for solutions. I used BeautifulSoup to get the csrf token from `/login` and then sent it using a POST request to the `/login/password`. Here's the code

```
def login(session, LOGIN_URL_GET, LOGIN_URL_POST, username, password):
    page = session.get(LOGIN_URL_GET)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    csrf = soup.find('input', {'name': '_csrf'}).get('value')

    login_data = dict(username=username, password=password, _csrf=csrf, next='/')
    session.post(LOGIN_URL_POST, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=LOGIN_URL_GET))
```

Then I use the `connect.sid` thingy that ExpressJS gives to the session like this.

```
with requests.Session() as reqs:
    login(reqs, LOGIN_URL_GET, LOGIN_URL_POST, username, password)
    connection_sid = reqs.cookies["connect.sid"]
    reqs.close()
    do_whatever(connection_sid)
```

Edit: Not 100% sure about the `connect.sid`, should I do it this way?